# (Done) I think the question about employees putting lives at risk should be reopened

Tags: discussion, reopen-request

[I am endangering people's lives doing tasks I am not qualified to do](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/179195/i-am-endangering-peoples-lives-doing-tasks-i-am-not-qualified-to-do)

Yes, the OP may be asking what they should do, but I don't believe the answers in this question actually adds no value to others.

I'm guessing this IS a scenario that occurs from time to time, and letting this stay up will act a resource for those that are put in a tricky position.

Nobody here is able to decide what the OP should do. But we certainly can make persuasive arguments about what their next steps should be.

Comment: I reopened it, I agree that it both a useful and answerable question.